# Google cloud: Dataproc taking too long to start the explorer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

After cluster creation, the jupyter lab takes too long to load the files, especially if you want to navigate to a GCP bucket path.

Comment: Did you specify the GCS dir with the `dataproc:jupyter.notebook.gcs.dir` property?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the reason why this takes too long to load but there is a very simple hack to overcome long waiting times.

So, when you open the jupyter lab from the **web interfaces** tab on the **cluster details** page, you get a page with some URL like: *https://lorem-ipsum-dot-asia-southeast1.dataproc.googleusercontent.com/gateway/default/jupyter/lab/*.

Now what you can do to navigate to your directory directly, is to modify the above URL to something like this: https://lorem-ipsum-dot-asia-southeast1.dataproc.googleusercontent.com/gateway/default/jupyter/lab/tree/GCS/users/experiments/exp1.

i.e. just modify the URL to the desired path.

I know this may sound obvious and dumb and straightforward but its a life saver if you were waiting for 20-25 mins just for the explorer to load your files.